# I cannot find how I can access DI properties from a child class

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, ngx-admin, nebula

I have implemented [this](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/auth/custom-auth-components#custom-auth-components) approach on my angular app and login/registration are working.

Now I wish to add a function to run OnInit when my custome registration/login components are initialized.

> Specifically I wish to use/inject

1. MyService
2. ActivatedRoute/ActivatedRouteSnapshot to access url params on the two components.
3. LocationStrategy

> into my child components (LoginComponent and RegistrationComponent) because they all derive from 
>   NbLoginComponent and NbRegisterComponent respectively

Here is my register.component.ts

```
export class NgxRegisterComponent extends NbRegisterComponent {}
```

Here is my NbRegisterComponent

```
export declare class NbRegisterComponent {

    constructor(
        service: NbAuthService, 
        options: {}, 
        cd: ChangeDetectorRef, 
        router: Router);

    register(): void;

    getConfigValue(key: string): any;

    static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<NbRegisterComponent>;

    static ɵcmp: ɵngcc0.ɵɵComponentDefWithMeta<NbRegisterComponent, "nb-register", never, {}, {}, never>;
}
```

I am stuck in that I cannot use Injector on NbRegisterComponent because the constructor wont accept any properties, not arguments.

Also, I tried declaring protected members in NbRegisterComponent and added it to the constructor

```
protected myService : MyService
```

Then in the child class, RegisterComponent, I added the properties to constructor's and Super()'s arguments but the injected properties were all null/undefined.

Any help would go a long way.

Comment: if you extend you should have access to the parent methods without injecting them again. Static methods don't have access to this though

Comment: Returns an undefined object. 

This seems to be a similar issue but I cannot understand it well enough. 

https://github.com/akveo/nebular/issues/1234

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hehehe,

In the child component I added a list of providers for all the objects/properties needed like

```
@Component({
  //...
  providers: [
    {provide: VisitsService, useClass : VisitsService},
  ]
})
```

Here after in the constructor of the child component I appended the @Inject() function as

```
  constructor(
    @Inject(ActivatedRoute)activateRoute : ActivatedRoute,
    @Inject(VisitsService) protected visitService: VisitsService,    
  ){
    super(
      activateRoute, 
      visitService);
  }
```

Now everything works.

> Oh! remember the parent components also injected these properties to its constructor and the order of arguments matters.